# Parsing JSON Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

The following JSON object that I have got

```
console.log(message.payloadString)
```

that outputs the following object:

> "{FieldName=str,
>   FieldValue={"myValue":{"Name":GPS,"value":29.889}}}"

Using the following Code, I would like to get the Name rpoperty, in this case "GPS"

```
var payload = JSON.parse(
    (message.payloadString).substring(
        (message.payloadString).indexOf('FieldValue=')+"FieldValue=".length,
        (message.payloadString).length - 1)
    )
);

update(payload.myValue.Name);
```

However once I run the code, it gives me

> Unexpected token R error.

Comment: So debug your code to find out which values are not what you expect.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: He's attempting to take the substring that is valid JSON.

Comment: @squint Ah, yes. I read the parentheses wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisHayes No, you were right. That isn't valid JSON. `{"Name":GPS,` ?

Comment: You should stop using `(x.y).substring` and `(x,y).indexOf`, that's really ugly and overcomplicating your code. Just use `x.y.indexOf` etc. Several of us had a hard time reading your code because of all the redundant parenthesis.

Comment: FYI: `payloadString` is *not* a JSON string.  Also, there's no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: I really hate it when people don't take the time to property format their questions. This user has asked over 100 questions, and still can't manage to give it a little effort.

Comment: What is `message`?  How is `message.payloadString` being generated?  Can you fix that so it's a valid JSON string to begin with?

Comment: Thanks Rocket, I have got the point.In the backend there is something needed to be fixed. Thanks your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-string doesn't contain valid JSON.

```
"Name":GPS
```

will cause a parse error.

However, I'm unable reproduce your *specific* unexpected token; I get 'G', not 'R'.

```
x = '{FieldName=str, FieldValue={"myValue":{"Name":GPS,"value":29.889}}}'

// x.length - 1 is redundant, but I've included it anyways
x = x.substring(x.indexOf('FieldValue=') + 'FieldValue='.length, x.length - 1)

// x == '{"myValue":{"Name":GPS,"value":29.889}}'

JSON.parse(x) // error
```

yields:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token G
```

Comment: Hello Meager, sorry for the confusion. Yes I would like to get substring which contains valid json object then I would like to parse it.

Comment: @casillas: Your string does not contain a valid JSON string.

Comment: May I only get {"myValue":{"Name":GPS,"value":29.889}} that string?

Comment: @casillas: You *are* getting that string.  That part works fine.  The error is that string is **not** valid JSON.  Why isn't `GPS` in double quotes?